# Open source c++ program that receives GPS (NMEA) sentences or x,y coordination and play a location on a map

Tags: c++, gps

My program reads GPS (NMEA) sentences from the serial port. I want to be able to see the location in those sentences (some of which contain x,y coordinates) in a map.

Is there a library (preferable open source) I can use to to that?

(It would really help me if it will work on both Linux and Windows, but if not, Windows is OK too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the map component for system integration or just for diagnostic purposes?  If just for diagnostic purposes, it might be easier to load the points into a web GIS solution such as [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) or [Esri's ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer).  ArcGIS Explorer is stand-alone, but Google Maps can be embedded.  With Google, you'll  have to use JavaScript to design the control.

In the Java world, [OpenMap](http://openmap.bbn.com/) is popular.

If you need an open source C++ library, consider [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page).  It is a collaborative project that provide users and developers tools for mapping.  In particular, checkout the [frameworks wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) for a list of widgets and tools to use their framework.  I believe they have C++ widgets you can leverage (although I haven't tried it myself).

For OSM, the widget controls for C++ are [COSMCtrl](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/COSMCtrl) (MFC), [Marble](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Marble) (Qt), and [QMapControl](http://www.medieninf.de/qmapcontrol/) (Qt).

I'm certain there are other open source C++ widgets out there, but I don't have experience with them.

Comment: I couldn't fine how do I use OpenStreetMap in my code. I mean - I want to be able to call a function like 'show(int Xcoord,int Ycoord)', and that I'll see the location on a map. ( maybe in new popup window).

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt you'll find anything *that* simple.  With GIS frameworks, you typically have to embed a map widget/control into your UI application.  Then you'll use the framework's geometry data type to convert your lat/lon coordinates into a geometry and then you'll add the geometry to a layer onto the map object.  For desktop apps, you'll need to configure the map to use the same spatial reference as your points.  The web viewers are fixed at web mercator so you'll need to actually translate/project your points to see them correctly.  GIS is always a bit of work.

Comment: thanks Jordan. I find it hard to believe that I cant find something that simple...

Comment: Let me know if you find anything.  Embedding a browser control with Google Maps might be your quickest way to simply plotting points.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

http://nmea.sourceforge.net/#platforms ?

Comment: where does it say it presents anything on a  map?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't read that you also need to display you position on the map... Of course the answer oc Jordan in infinitely more complete than mine